# How to get three separate RewriteRule conditions to not overlap

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure an .htaccess file to do three separate things:

1. If the request is for a file or directory on the server, just serve that
2. If the request follows a specific pattern used for link shortening, send it to that php file
3. Everything else gets sent to an [IPFS](https://ipfs.io) gateway which I have a subdomain pointing to via DNS

So far I can get it to do 1 & 2 but any way I add the IPFS redirect tries to send all requests there, and often breaks the correct requests to the gateway (ends up looking for index.wml files instead of .html).

The flow structure I'm using is from [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#browser-dependent-content) apache documentation.

Any suggestions?

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f   
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "/([0-9a-z]{5}|[0-9a-z]{3}\+?)$".    
RewriteRule "^.*$" "/yourls-loader.php" [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://ipfs.mydomain.com/$1 [P, L]
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook was most helpful, and I got it working. We added some skip flags as well as a DirectoryIndex rule.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L,S=2]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "/([0-9a-z]{4,5}\+?)$"
RewriteRule "^.*$" "/yourls-loader.php" [L,S=1]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://ipfs.ashp.land/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```